# How to group jQuery functionality with grouped elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My document contains grouped elements and with those elements comes functionality. I would like to be able to take this group of elements and their interaction with each other and place it wherever on the page when possible.

When I try to do this, my current jQuery code tries to change elements of one group while the other group is being interacted with. How do I keep these groups and their functionality seperated but able to use the same piece of jQuery functionality (preventing having to write double funcitonality)?

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/8pg3ht52/) is my code:

```js
//If value of Dropdown 1 has been changed, do the following:
$( ".dd-first-check" ).change(function() {
  var selectedValue = $(".dd-first-check").val();

  //If the selected option has a value assigned to it, execute the following:
  if(selectedValue)
  {
    //$("#Dropdown1-error").hide();
    $( "#Dropdown1-error" ).addClass( "d-none" );
    $(".dd-second-check option").show();
    //Do something else
    //alert(selectedValue);
  }

}).trigger( "change" );

//Whenever Dropdown 2 has been clicked and Dropdown 1 value has not yet been set, show validation error:
$(".dd-second-check").click(function() {
 //If the selected option does not have a value assigned to it, execute the following:
  if(!$(".dd-first-check").val())
  {
   //Show validation message:
    //$("#Dropdown1-error").show();
    $( "#Dropdown1-error" ).removeClass( "d-none" );
    $(this).blur().focus();
  }
});

//Don't allow Dropdown 2 value to change when Dropdown 1 does not contain a selected value
//(this prevents "wrong" data from being send when DOM is manually edited on client side):
$( ".dd-second-check" ).change(function(e) {
  if(!$(".dd-first-check").val())
  {
    alert("No option was selected in previous dropdown.");
    
    //TO DO: Still requires some code
    //e.preventDefault;
  }
});
```

```css
.dd-second-check option
{
  display: none;
}

.dd-group-1
{
  background-color: green;
}

.dd-group-2
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dd-first-check">Group 1 Dropdown 1:</label>
          <select class="form-control dd-first-check dd-group-1">
            <option disabled selected="selected">Choose an option...</option>
            <option value="1">Please load in more options...</option>
            <option value="2">Example option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Example option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Example option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Example option 5</option>
          </select>
          <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Dropdown 1" data-valmsg-replace="true">
            <span id="Dropdown1-error" class="d-none">Dropdown 1 field is required.</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dd-second-check">Group 1 Dropdown 2:</label>
          <select id="group-1" class="form-control dd-second-check dd-group-1">
            <option disabled selected="selected">Choose an option...</option>
            <option>Please load in more options...</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group-2" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dd-first-check">Group 2 Dropdown 1:</label>
          <select class="form-control dd-first-check dd-group-2">
            <option disabled selected="selected">Choose an option...</option>
            <option value="1">Please load in more options...</option>
            <option value="2">Example option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Example option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Example option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Example option 5</option>
          </select>
          <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Dropdown 1" data-valmsg-replace="true">
            <span id="Dropdown2-error" class="d-none">Dropdown 1 field is required.</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dd-second-check">Group 2 Dropdown 2:</label>
          <select class="form-control dd-second-check dd-group-2">
            <option disabled selected="selected">Choose an option...</option>
            <option>Please load in more options...</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Whenever I click the last dropdown element from the second group, jQuery will be executed for the validation element with that `ID`. So I need to get the ID of the validation element that belongs to that group. Is there a way I could make a relation between elements like this happen and make sure that the groups won't interact with each other whilst keeping the functionality of the first two drop down elements?

My goal is reusability.

Comment: Well you have multiple elements with the same class and you target it by class so it will of course use the first one.  So you need to change the code to look for an element under the same parent or a sibling and do the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your fiddle to look for the element within a parent group and to use classes rather than id's for you error spans. The rows have an additional class called group.

This is used to find the current item's parent with a class of group.  That parent is then searched for the second element.

You need to ensure that you are only looking within the group

```js
//If value of Dropdown 1 has been changed, do the following:
$( ".dd-first-check" ).change(function() {
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  //Get the parent group element
  var $group = $(this).parents('.group');
  //If the selected option has a value assigned to it, execute the following:
  if(selectedValue)
  {
    //$("#Dropdown1-error").hide();
    $group.find( ".dropdown-error" ).addClass( "d-none" );
    $group.find(".dd-second-check option").show();
    //Do something else
    //alert(selectedValue);
  }

}).trigger( "change" );

//Whenever Dropdown 2 has been clicked and Dropdown 1 value has not yet been set, show validation error:
$(".dd-second-check").click(function() {
  //Get the parent group element
  var $group = $(this).parents('.group');
 //If the selected option does not have a value assigned to it, execute the following:
  if(!$group.find(".dd-first-check").val())
  {
   //Show validation message:
    //$("#Dropdown1-error").show();
    $group.find( ".dropdown-error" ).removeClass( "d-none" );
    $(this).blur().focus();
  }
});

//Don't allow Dropdown 2 value to change when Dropdown 1 does not contain a selected value
//(this prevents "wrong" data from being send when DOM is manually edited on client side):
$( ".dd-second-check" ).change(function(e) {
  //Get the parent group element
  var $group = $(this).parents('.group');
  if(!$group.find(".dd-first-check").val())
  {
    alert("No option was selected in previous dropdown.");
    
    //TO DO: Still requires some code
    //e.preventDefault;
  }
});
```

```css
.dd-second-check option
{
  display: none;
}

.dd-group-1
{
  background-color: green;
}

.dd-group-2
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row group">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dd-first-check">Group 1 Dropdown 1:</label>
          <select class="form-control dd-first-check dd-group-1">
            <option disabled selected="selected">Choose an option...</option>
            <option value="1">Please load in more options...</option>
            <option value="2">Example option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Example option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Example option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Example option 5</option>
          </select>
          <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Dropdown 1" data-valmsg-replace="true">
            <span class="dropdown-error d-none">Dropdown 1 field is required.</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dd-second-check">Group 1 Dropdown 2:</label>
          <select id="group-1" class="form-control dd-second-check dd-group-1">
            <option disabled selected="selected">Choose an option...</option>
            <option>Please load in more options...</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row group">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dd-first-check">Group 2 Dropdown 1:</label>
          <select class="form-control dd-first-check dd-group-2">
            <option disabled selected="selected">Choose an option...</option>
            <option value="1">Please load in more options...</option>
            <option value="2">Example option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Example option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Example option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Example option 5</option>
          </select>
          <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Dropdown 1" data-valmsg-replace="true">
            <span class="dropdown-error d-none">Dropdown 1 field is required.</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dd-second-check">Group 2 Dropdown 2:</label>
          <select class="form-control dd-second-check dd-group-2">
            <option disabled selected="selected">Choose an option...</option>
            <option>Please load in more options...</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: So you would basically use `.parent` and `.find` (in jQuery) for approaching problems like these? Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, but actually using parents, which will walk up the dom tree until  it finds the selector.  Parent will only look at the first parent